# Changing One Tag Name in an XML File Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible for me to have a conditional in XSLT such that I find and replace only the FIRST tag of a particular tag name?

For example, I have an XML file with many `<title>` tags. I would like to replace the first of these tags with `<PageTitle>`. The rest should be left alone. How would I do this in my transform? What I currently have is this:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
     <PageTitle>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </PageTitle>
</xsl:template>
```

which finds all `<title>` tags and replaces them with `<PageTitle>`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a correct and complete solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The first `title` element in the document is selected by**:

**`(//title)[1]`**

Many people mistakenly think that `//title[1]` selects the first `title` in the document and this is a frequently committed error. `//title[1]` selects every `title` element that is the first `title` child of its parent -- not what is wanted here.

**Using this, the following transformation produces the required output**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "title[count(.|((//title)[1])) = 1]">

     <PageTitle>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </PageTitle>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
 <a>
  <b>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </b>
 </a>
 <b>
  <title/>
 </b>
 <c>
  <title/>
 </c>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<t>
 <a>
  <b>
    <PageTitle>Page Title</PageTitle>
  </b>
 </a>
 <b>
  <title />
 </b>
 <c>
  <title />
 </c>
</t>
```

**Do note how we use the well-known Kaysian method of set intersection in XPath 1.0**:

If there are two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`, the following expression selects every node which belongs to both `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

**`$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]`**

**In the specific case when both node-sets contain only one node**, and one of them is the current node, the following expression evaluates to `true()` exactly when the two nodes are identical:

**`count(.|$ns2) = 1`**

A variation of this is used in the match pattern of the template that overrides the identity rule:

**`title[count(.|((//title)[1])) = 1]`**

matches only the first `title` element in the document.

Comment: It would be good if you also commented on the difference between `(//title)[1]` and `//title[1]` as that's not the most obvious thing.

Comment: @krab, `title[not(preceding::title)]` may not match the first `title` element in some XML documents. Do you need an example, or are you able to find it yourself? :)

Comment: are you referring to the possibility of nested title elements like Alohci pointed out, and the need for checking for ancestor::title as well, or are there other issues with the approach?

Answer (score 3):

This one should work:

```
<xsl:template match="title[1]">
     <PageTitle>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </PageTitle>
</xsl:template>
```

But it matches first title in every context. So in the following example, both `/a/x/title[1]` and `/a/title[1]` will get matched. So you might want to specify something like `match="/a/title[1]"`.

```
<a>
    <x>
        <title/> <!-- first title in the context -->
    </x>
    <title/> <!-- first title in the context -->
    <title/>
    <c/>
    <title/>
</a>
```

Comment: This template will be applied to every `title` element that is the first child of its parent -- not to the first `title` element in the document.

Comment: Well, if you would have actually read the answer, this comment wouldn't be necessary... Hint: try reading the second sentence, starting with "But".

Comment: The second part of your solution still doesn't select the first `title` element in some specific XML documents. What if it is not known in advance that the name of the top element will be `a`? Or, if it is not known if the first `title` element will be a child of the top element? Do you need a specific example, or can you find it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

If all the title tags are siblings, you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="title[1]">
    <PageTitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </PageTitle>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this will match all `title` elements that are the first child of any node. If titles may have different parent nodes, and you only want the first title in the entire document to be replaced with `PageTitle`, you can use

```
<xsl:template match="title[not(preceding::title or ancestor::title)]">
    <PageTitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </PageTitle>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: title[not(preceding::title)] will fail if the first title element itself contains a title element. title[not(preceding::title or ancestor::title)] would be better.

Comment: I see that you corrected this solution: now it is OK and I reversed my downvote :)